# Permanent changes with "onclick" handler?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, facebook, onclick

I'm attempting to modify an app for facebook that uses php and javascript.

It allows a user to send gifts to each other's wall. When a gift is received, it show's on the app's notification page for that user.

**The problem:** after a gift is accepted, it still shows on the notifications page. I suppose because it was deemed necessary in order for the point system as well as the history functions to operate properly. It appears that gifts older than 30 days are no longer displayed. I tried to permanently change the date of the gift after it's accepted.

Can anyone please suggest possible ways to:

**Option 1.** After the gift is accepted, permanently change it to a different image to inform the user "you have already accepted this". Without removing it from the database.

**Option 2.** Remove the gift from the page (or prevent it from being displayed) after it's accepted...without deleting it from the database. .hide and display:none; are not viable options because the gift will be displayed again...every time the page loads.

**Option 3.** Last and least desired option, remove the gift from the page and database as well.

The original code for that page is below. The part of the code that I'm guessing needs to be modified is located between the asterisk dividers. I hope it's not too difficult to follow :-/
Thanks for your time.

```
<?php

if(!isset($facebook))
{
  $user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
}
else
{
  $user_id=$user_info['UserID'];
}

$news_limit=$current_time-2592000;

$history_query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$exchange_table." WHERE Time>'$news_limit'      
AND ReceiverID='$user_id' ORDER BY Time DESC"); 
$history_num=mysql_num_rows($history_query); ?>

<div style="font-size:14px;width:720px;padding:10px;<?php echo $background_one; ?>"   
align="left">
  <div style="font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;color:#6f6f6f;">
   <?php echo $nav_info['home']; ?>
  </div>
  <div style="width:100%;margin-top:10px;" align="center">
    <img src="<?php echo $app_info['image_url']; ?>divider.gif">
    <img src="<?php echo $app_info['image_url']; ?>divider.gif">
    <img src="<?php echo $app_info['image_url']; ?>divider.gif">
  </div> <?php

    if($history_num>0)
    { 
      $gift_query=mysql_query("SELECT GiftID,Name,Image FROM ".$gift_table." WHERE   
Type='1'"); 

      while($gift_info=mysql_fetch_assoc($gift_query))
      {
        $gift_array[$gift_info['GiftID']]['name']=$gift_info['Name'];
        $gift_array[$gift_info['GiftID']]['image']=$gift_info['Image'];
     } ?>

      <div style=""> <?php

        $i=1;

        while($history_info=mysql_fetch_assoc($history_query))
        { ?>
          <div style="margin-top:10px;">
            <div style="float:left;width:75px;">
              <img src="<?php echo  
$app_info['upload_url'].$gift_array[$history_info['GiftID']]['image']; ?>"   
style="width:75px;height:75px;">
            </div>
            <div style="float:left;margin-left:10px;">
              <span style="font-size:18px;"><span id="month<?php echo $i; ?>"></span> -   
Gift Received!</span><br>
              You received a(n) <b><?php echo $gift_array[$history_info['GiftID']]    
['name']; ?></b> from <b><fb:name uid='<?php echo $history_info['FacebookID']; ?>'   
linked='false'></fb:name></b>!<br>
**************************************************************
<input id="share_button<?php echo $i; ?>" onclick="shareFeed('<?php echo   
$gift_array[$history_info['GiftID']]['image']; ?>','<?php echo $history_info['GiftID'];   
?>','<?php echo $gift_array[$history_info['GiftID']]['name']; ?>')" type="image" src="  
<?php echo $app_info['image_url']; ?>share_button.png"    
onmouseover="convert('share_button<?php echo $i; ?>','share_hover.png')"   
onmouseout="convert('share_button<?php echo $i; ?>','share_button.png')"    
style="height:29px;margin-top:5px;">
</div>
**************************************************************
            <br style="clear:both;">
          </div> 
          <script>
            var date_text="";
            var time_date=new Date();
            var monthNames= 


["January","February","March","April","May",
"June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];

            time_date.setTime(<?php echo $history_info['Time']*1000; ?>);

            document.getElementById('month<?php echo $i; ?  
>').innerHTML=monthNames[time_date.getMonth()]+" "+time_date.getDate();
          </script> <?php

          $i++;
        } ?>

      </div> <?php
    }
    else
    { ?>
      <div style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;margin-top:20px;" align="center">
        No giftss received over the past 30 days.
      </div> <?php
    } ?>

</div>
```